# How to keep website with in 960px but streach background on x-axis

Tags: html, css

I am putting entire website inside a div with ID container. The css for container is

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: left;
}
```

But the problem is that it also limits the background to 960px. I want to exclude background & allow it to fill entire screen. i.e repeat on x-axis

Comment: on div outside of #container div with width 100% and background as you wanted

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code - should work :

**CSS**

```
body {
width: 100%;
background: #fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <div id="container">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that,

First set your body's margin(left and right) to "auto", this way anything under the body will be centered.

So, 
Here's the first code:

```
body{
    margin: 0px auto;/* Centers your page */
    background-color: #898989; /* Add a nice background-color */
}
```

There, Now for the div,
It is important to have a width defined for the div
so, assuming that your div is having an id called container:

```
#container{
    width: 960px;
}
```

'

That's it! :D
I hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Put `background` on parent element, eg. `body`.

```
body {background: url('...') repeat-x};
#container {width: 960px; ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

just put what you want for background in body tag

```
body {
   background:whatever_you_want;
}
```